# Xlookup on one table from another table in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, variables, listobject, xlookup

I have two tables - `CNSTimeVariance` table in one workbook and `WorseCase` Table in a file called `Financial Model v12.xlsx` which I find and open as the most recent file in a directory. The variable associated to this file is `targetFilename`. The issue is that this file name will change  every now and then and I want to make it dynamic. How can I replace `Financial Model v12.xlsx` in the xlookup formula given in last line of following code with `targetFilename`?

```vb
SUB Xlookup()

    Sheets("CNS Time Total").Select

    Dim CNSTimeVariance As ListObject
    Set CNSTimeVariance = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("CNSTimeVariance")

    Dim DWB As Workbook
    Set DWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As File
    Dim myFolder
    Dim targetFilename As String
    Dim dteFile As Date

    Const myDir As String = "C:\My Desktop Folders\Edge\7. Financial Models\"
    
    Set FileSys = New FileSystemObject
    Set myFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(myDir)
        
    dteFile = DateSerial(1900, 1, 1)
    For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
        If objFile.DateLastModified > dteFile Then
            dteFile = objFile.DateLastModified
            targetFilename = objFile.Name
        End If
    Next objFile

    MsgBox targetFilename

    Workbooks.Open (myDir & targetFilename)
            
    'Set FileSys = Nothing
    'Set myFolder = Nothing

    DWB.Activate

    Range("CNSTimeVariance[P Hours]").FormulaR1C1 = _
       "=XLOOKUP(CNSTimeVariance[@Helper],'Financial Model v12.xlsx'!WorseCase[Helper],'Financial Model v12.xlsx'!WorseCase[P Hours],""Not Found"")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the variable into the formula string

```vb
 Range("CNSTimeVariance[P Hours]").FormulaR1C1 = "=XLOOKUP(CNSTimeVariance[@Helper],'" & _
       targetFilename & "'!WorseCase[Helper],'" & _
       targetFilename & "'!WorseCase[P Hours],""Not Found"")"
```

Comment: Worked like magic. Many thanks. I have been stuck on this for days actually. Also when you have time, if you could explain why do we need to do this? Like why is the targetFilename is enclosed in &

Comment: @shoaib You have to split the string into the variable and non-variable parts and then join them with `&` so the variable is not enclosed in quotes. `"targetFilename"` is just the string `targetFilename` not its value  `workbookname.xlsx`